# Add css class to a javascript event

Tags: javascript

how can I add a class to the following element?

```
window.location = 'page.html';
```

for example, i'd like to get this result:

```
<a href="page.html" class="nameclass">link</a>
```

but my javascript page loads automatically after a function, not with a link text to click on.

Comment: `window.location = 'page.html';` this statement upon execution would redirect automatically only .i dont get it, what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Add css class to a javascript event?!

Comment: use jQuery instead. [Free Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwnNj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a link element:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
// <a></a>
```

Add an href:

```
a.href = 'page.html';
// <a href="page.html"></a>
```

Add a class:

```
a.className = 'nameclass';
// <a href="page.html" class="nameclass"></a>
```

Add some text:

```
a.innerHTML = 'link';
// <a href="page.html" class="nameclass">link</a>
```

Append it to the body element:

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
// In your page!
```